# Getting all application defined configs as key/value in Aspnet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to get all the application defined configs (from appsettings.json in my case) in a key/value pair. The `IConfiguration.AsEnumerable()` does return all the configs but it has lot more that what is defined by the application. From this list, there is no way to get the context of where the config is coming from. I only want to get the configurations that application has defined.
Other option i tried was to iterate the `CondigurationRoot.Providers` and filter out the `JsonConfigurationProvider` but i see that 'Data' property is not exposed and there is no public API to get it either.

Any other API that i am missing and i should look into?

Comment: Why don't you just build your own `IConfiguration`, using only `appsettings.json`? Something like `new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true).Build();`

Comment: Also you can use you own class to map config on its properties - so there will be only settings that correspond to this class properties

Comment: @FedericoDipuma thanks that is one workaround i can look into. 'CreateDefaultBuilder' already loads both settings and secrets file for me and i wanted to leverage the same configuration to retrieve my configs that powers dashboard for me. While i can create another ConfigurationBuilder, it does seem like unnecessary overhead of loading the configs twice.

Comment: @PavelAgarkov I don't have classes for all the configs. They are multi level json files we have access them just the string keys.

Comment: Having class for each config is much more reliable and you also will be able to use IOption<T> to inject those configs directly into places where you need them